# Finding limes superior and limes inferior

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> > Find the limes superior and the limes inferior of the sequence
> >     $$
> > c_k=\frac{k+(-1)^k(2k+1)}{k}, k\in\mathbb{N}_+.
> > $$

Do not know if there is a special way to find limit points... my idea is to look separately at the positive and the negative $c_k$.

$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k+2k+1}{k}=3,~~~\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k-(2k+1)}{k}=-1.
$$
So the sequence does have the limit points $3$ and $-1$ at least.
But how can I know if there are more limit points?

If not, then $3$ is the limes superior and $-1$ is the limes inferior.

Comment: You can't make a mojito without limes!

Comment: Excuse me? What do you mean?

Comment: @mathfemi It's a sort of joke, usually in English one says "limit", and "lime" is the name of a fruit.

Comment: As for the math, the behavior of the sequences might be a little clearer if you split the terms and cancel $k$ where you can.

Answer (score 2):

When $k$ is odd
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\substack{k\to\infty\\k\text{ odd}}}\frac{k+(-1)^k(2k+1)}k
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2k+1-(4k+3)}{2k+1}\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{-2k-2}{2k+1}\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{-2-2/k}{2+1/k}\\
&=-1
\end{align}
$$
when $k$ is even
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\substack{k\to\infty\\k\text{ odd}}}\frac{k+(-1)^k(2k+1)}k
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2k+(4k+1)}{2k}\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{6k+1}{2k}\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{6+1/k}{2}\\
&=3
\end{align}
$$
Since $k$ must be even or odd, this handles all the limit points. Thus, the limsup is $3$ and the liminf is $-1$.